# Do I have to install drivers after an installation?

Tags: drivers

Do I have to install drivers for all of my devices after I install Ubuntu?  Does Ubuntu have generic drivers for most computer equipment (video, audio, network adapters)

Comment: Has most drivers.  Use a LiveDVD to boot to verify most component.

Comment: Is the hardware working?  Then no.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will install most drivers automatically, and it recognizes quite a bit of hardware. Some of it might require proprietary drivers, though. You have to decide if you're philosophically ok with that.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)